# Creating association for users with predefined data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hey any help would be appreciated!

Basically I have two models - User (using Devise) and Sport

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sports
end

class Sport < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I have a predefined list of Sports that are seeded into my database (e.g. Running, Weightlifting etc). What I want to do is have a user login and then select which sports they do and have that saved through an association. This then allows the user to search for and see what sports other users do etc.

I have managed to create associations through the console like this:

```
user = User.find(1)
sport = Sport.find(1)
user.sports << sport
```

but I can't figure how to translate that to a form.

So far I've got this even though all it does is create a new Sport (which I don't want):

```
#sports_controller.rb
def index
  @sports = Sport.where(["name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%"])
end

def new
  @sport = Sports.new
end

def create
  @sport = current_user.sports.create(sports_params)
end

private
 def sports_params
 params.require(:sport).permit(:name)
end
```

and then for my form:

```
#sports/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @sport do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :exercises %><br>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :name, Sport.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Is it right doing it through this controller? I'm really lost as to how to do this and it's a core functionality for my uni project.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using Devise for user login?

Comment: Hey, yes I am. Sorry I'll edit my post and put that in!

Comment: OK, I will get back with an answer shortly.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I would get rid of your SportsController, this feels like you are updating a User only. The SportsController would be for creating Sports themselves, which you don't need to do as you are seeding them)

So if you haven't got one already, add the user routes (this won't allow updating devise fields e.g password, but that's outside of the scope of this question):

```
resources :users
```

Then in your ApplicationController, add this method:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(_resource)
  edit_user_path(current_user)
end
```

That will redirect the user after signin to their edit page.

Finally the form:

```
#users/edit.html.erb

<%= form_for @user do |form| %>

  <% @sports.each do |sport| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "user[sport_ids][]", sport.id, form.object.sports.include?(sport) %>
    <%= sport.name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will pass up an array of sport_ids, which will automatically associate all the selected sports with your user, due to Rails magic :). The magic being  you can also associate objects like so:

```
@model.associated_model_ids << [1,2,3]
```

And your UsersController:

```
def UsersController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @sports = Sport.all.order(name: :asc)
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end 

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])    
  end  

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(sport_ids: [])
  end
end
```

You will need to add the user show.html.erb template but that should be enough to get you going. I think there is a nicer way to do the checkboxes so I might update this later, but that should work.

Example to see if it worked:

```
#users/show.html.erb

<%= @users.sports.map(&:name).join(', ') %>
```

Comment: Absolutely amazing! It works perfectly thank you. Been trying to do this for so long. Only one thing: When I'm on the edit page I have the checkboxes working however I also have this displayed right after: [#<Sport id: 4, name: "Cylcing", created_at: "2017-02-17 11:22:12", updated_at: "2017-02-17 11:22:12">, #<Sport id: 6, name: "Gymnastics", created_at: "2017-02-17 11:24:43", updated_at: "2017-02-17 11:24:43">]

Comment: Ah, I included an extra = by mistake, see my update in one moment

Comment: I have updated the answer, copy the new edit.html.erb I posted instead. I changed <%= sports.each do |sport| %> to <% sports.each do |sport| %> (the equals outputs that line in the browser, which as it's an each is actually an object which is what you are seeing).

Comment: Ahhh! Of course.. I didn't even copy and paste I wrote it out and still missed that haha. Seriously thank you so much though man, I couldn't appreciate this more!

Comment: No worries, glad it helped.

Comment: Hey, I've been working on my project and was just revisiting this for styling. I'm trying to style my checkboxes but that relies on the label name being the same as the input name. Do you know how to do this? I've tried a few different things but I can't get the label to match "user[sport_ids][]". Thanks in advance!